# I want to import things from txt and view them in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I want to do a table of years and some ids so there will be only 2 columns I have a txt file that has information but in that file information like that `456445 - 2000` the thing I want to do is on the image

Do a table search and find the year from id or the reverse

[The expected thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuj3J.png)

Comment: At least you need to show what you have attempted. (show your code)

Comment: @KenLee the things is i dont know PHP or SQL i will learn it in the future but before that i should do the thing i said

Comment: So i didnt write any code yet :(

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a free code writing service. We are not here to do your work for you. We are here to offer help if you have problems you cannot solve yourself. But for that you need to actually implement your solution yourself. I understand that you do not know programming or database logic. But that is something you cannot get around learning. And you need to learn it _before_ you can implement a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, take your text file into Google Spreadsheet. Where your PHPMyAdmin and excel column names will be the same. Then download The File as CSV File. Then go to PHPMyAdmin and select the table in which you want to import the CSV file. Then click on Import from the menu bar and then import your CSV file from the Import CSV Option.